# what is different with two version code of my second activity?

Tags: android, sqlite

this is source code of MainAcitivity

```
 package dhyna.inventory;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public PengolahDatabase mydb;
    private ListView listData = null;
    private SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mydb = new PengolahDatabase(this);
        db = mydb.getWritableDatabase();



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tampilSemuaProduk(db);
        listItemClickListener();
        mydb.close();

    }
    private void tampilSemuaProduk(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Cursor tampilCursor;

       tampilCursor = mydb.fetchAllWisata(db);


startManagingCursor(tampilCursor);
        String[] from = new String[]{mydb.ISI_TB_PRODUK[0], mydb.ISI_TB_PRODUK[1], mydb.ISI_TB_PRODUK[2], mydb.ISI_TB_PRODUK[3],mydb.ISI_TB_PRODUK[4]};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.tv_id, R.id.tv_produk, R.id.tv_kat, R.id.tv_hargabeli, R.id.tv_hargajual};
        SimpleCursorAdapter tampilAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, tampilCursor, from, to);
        listData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listData.setAdapter(tampilAdapter);


    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }



    public void listItemClickListener(){
        listData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                kirimParamIntent(position);
            }
        });
    }

    public void kirimParamIntent(int posisi) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TampilDetilProduk.class);
        intent.putExtra("idProduk", posisi++);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
}
```

this is my DBhelper class i give it name PengolahDataBase.java

```
    package dhyna.inventory;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class PengolahDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NAMA_DB    = "inventori";
    private final String TB_PRODUK = "produk";
   // private final String TB_KATEGORI    = "kategori";
    public final String[] ISI_TB_PRODUK = {"_id", "nama_produk", "id_kat", "harga_beli", "harga_jual"};
  //  public final String[] ISI_TB_KATEGORI   = {"_id", "nama_kategori"};



    PengolahDatabase (Context context){
        super(context, NAMA_DB, null, 1);
    }

    public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TB_PRODUK+"");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TB_PRODUK + "(" + ISI_TB_PRODUK[0] + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + ISI_TB_PRODUK[1] + " TEXT, " + ISI_TB_PRODUK[2] + " INTEGER, " + ISI_TB_PRODUK[3] + " INTEGER, " + ISI_TB_PRODUK[4] + " INTEGER)");
    }



    public void dataStandar (SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String[] produk = new String[]{"Marlboro", "Beras Tabanan", "Kopi Bola Dunia"};
        String[] kat = new String[]{"Rokok", "Sembako", "Sembako"};
        int[] hargaBeli = new int[]{19000, 199000, 20000};
        int[] hargaJual = new int[]{23000, 210000, 23000};
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        int i;
        int batas = produk.length - 1;
        for (i = 0; i <= batas; i++) {
            cv.put(ISI_TB_PRODUK[1], produk[i]);
            cv.put(ISI_TB_PRODUK[2], kat[i]);
            cv.put(ISI_TB_PRODUK[3], hargaBeli[i]);
            cv.put(ISI_TB_PRODUK[4], hargaJual[i]);
            db.insert(TB_PRODUK, null, cv);
            cv.clear();
        }
    }
    public Cursor fetchAllWisata(SQLiteDatabase db){
        return db.query(TB_PRODUK, new String[] {ISI_TB_PRODUK[0], ISI_TB_PRODUK[1], ISI_TB_PRODUK[2], ISI_TB_PRODUK[3], ISI_TB_PRODUK[4]},null , null, null, null, null);
    }
    public Barang ambilDetilProduk(SQLiteDatabase db,long idProduk){
        Log.v("info", "var db "+db);
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TB_PRODUK, new String[]{ISI_TB_PRODUK[0],ISI_TB_PRODUK[1]}, ISI_TB_PRODUK[0] + " = " + idProduk, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Barang barang = cursorToBarang(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return barang;


    }

    private Barang cursorToBarang(Cursor cursor) {
        Barang barang = new Barang();
        Log.v("info", "The GetLong " + cursor.getLong(0));
        barang.setIdProduk(cursor.getLong(0));
        barang.setNamaProduk(cursor.getString(1));
         return barang;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        createTable(db);
        dataStandar(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }


}
```

in MainAcitivity i make listView that show data from database. and this process work smothly. Also i make an event to process itemClick on listView. Where if i click a row in listView, it would be send a var that contains id and transfer it to second acitivity with intent. In second Activity, it will show data from DataBase that same as id from intent and show it up with TextView.

i have two version code of Second Activty(i give it name TampilDetilProduk.java). the first version the code run smoothly with no error. But in Second version there are an issue Java.nullPointerException so it will force close. and my question is What different of both?

this is an interface to save info from DB
    package dhyna.inventory;

```
/**
 * Created by Gung Bagus on 1/19/2016.
 */
public class Barang {

   private long idProduk ;
   private String namaProduk="Produk Tidak Ditemukan";
    private int hargaBeli, hargaJual;

    public Barang(){}

    public void setIdProduk(long id){
        this.idProduk = id;
    }
    public void setNamaProduk(String produk){
        this.namaProduk = produk;
    }
    public void setHargaBeli(int harga){
        this.hargaBeli = harga;
    }
    public void setHargaJual (int harga){
        this.hargaJual = harga;
    }
    public long getIdProduk(){
        return this.idProduk;
    }
    public String getNamaProduk() {
        return this.namaProduk;
    }
    public int getHargaBeli(){
        return this.hargaBeli;

    }
    public int getHargaJual(){
    return this.hargaJual;}


}
```

here the first version Second Activity

```
package dhyna.inventory;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TampilDetilProduk extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView namaProduk, namaKat, hargaBeli, hargaJual;
    ImageView tombolKembali;
    PengolahDatabase mydb;
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Barang barang= null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PengolahDatabase mydb = new PengolahDatabase(this);
        db = mydb.getWritableDatabase();
       Intent intent = getIntent();
        long idProduk = intent.getIntExtra("idProduk", 0) + 1;
        //Log.v("Info", "Nilai id Intent " + idProduk);

        barang = mydb.ambilDetilProduk(db, idProduk);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tampil_detil_produk);

       namaProduk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_produk_detil);

        namaProduk.setText(barang.getNamaProduk());



    }

    private void tampilkanProduk(SQLiteDatabase dbl) {
        namaProduk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_produk_detil);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        long idProduk = intent.getIntExtra("idProduk", 0) + 1;
        Log.v("Info", "Nilaiid Intent"+idProduk);

        barang = mydb.ambilDetilProduk(dbl, idProduk);
        namaProduk.setText(barang.getNamaProduk());

        }

    }
```

here the Second Version

```
package dhyna.inventory;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TampilDetilProduk extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView namaProduk, namaKat, hargaBeli, hargaJual;
    ImageView tombolKembali;
    PengolahDatabase mydb;
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Barang barang= null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PengolahDatabase mydb = new PengolahDatabase(this);
        db = mydb.getWritableDatabase();



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tampil_detil_produk);

        tampilkanProduk(db);


    }

    private void tampilkanProduk(SQLiteDatabase dbl) {
        namaProduk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_produk_detil);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        long idProduk = intent.getIntExtra("idProduk", 0) + 1;
        Log.v("Info", "Nilai id Intent"+idProduk);

        barang = mydb.ambilDetilProduk(dbl, idProduk);
        namaProduk.setText(barang.getNamaProduk());

        }

    }
```

and this is logCat

```
01-16 23:02:37.111 11917-11917/dhyna.inventory I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
01-16 23:02:37.111 11917-11917/dhyna.inventory W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 15952: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
01-16 23:02:37.111 11917-11917/dhyna.inventory D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
01-16 23:02:37.121 11917-11917/dhyna.inventory I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
01-16 23:02:37.121 11917-11917/dhyna.inventory W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 15952: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
01-16 23:02:37.121 11917-11917/dhyna.inventory D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
01-16 23:02:37.171 11917-11917/dhyna.inventory V/Info: Nilaiid Intent1
01-16 23:02:37.171 11917-11917/dhyna.inventory D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-16 23:02:37.171 11917-11917/dhyna.inventory W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b05930)
01-16 23:02:37.191 11917-11917/dhyna.inventory E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dhyna.inventory/dhyna.inventory.TampilDetilProduk}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                     at dhyna.inventory.TampilDetilProduk.tampilkanProduk(TampilDetilProduk.java:53)
                                                                     at dhyna.inventory.TampilDetilProduk.onCreate(TampilDetilProduk.java:38)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-16 23:02:38.561 11917-11917/dhyna.inventory I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11917 SIG: 9
```

sorry if my english and coding skill is so so bad.

Comment: add this line in  oncreate  namaProduk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_produk_detil);

Comment: you dont call tampilkanProduk() in the first one.... that's where the crash happens